# Can't set static IP address on Ubuntu 18.04

Tags: networking

I was assisting a customer with assigning a static IP address on one of our Ubuntu 18.04 virtual machines and then I realized how complicated finding the right instructions seemed.

According to https://linuxconfig.org/how-to-configure-static-ip-address-on-ubuntu-18-04-bionic-beaver-linux, you just simply:

1. Set the IP address configuration in the `/etc/network/interfaces` file, and then
2. Restart the networking service with: `systemctl restart networking.service`

However, when I run that, I just get the following error:

```
failed to restart networking.service: Unit networking.service not found
```

I have actually tried running the following commands, with none of them being successful:

```
ip a flush enp0s3
service networking restart
service network-manager restart
systemctl restart networking
systemctl restart networkmanager
systemctl restart networking.service
```

None of them work. I actually tried to install `network-manager` by running `apt install network-manager` and, while it installed successfully, restarting the service did not work.

Here's my `/etc/network/interfaces` file:

```
auto ens33
iface ens33 inet static
    address 192.168.1.50
    netmask 255.255.255.0
    gateway 192.168.1.1
    namesever 1.1.1.1
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Ubuntu 18 uses Netplan by default and needs configured through Netplan - why are you using `/etc/network/interfaces`?

Comment: Wasn't aware that this changed... Thanks for pointing me in the right direction.

Comment: However, it is very easy to set the static IP in Network Manager. For example: https://linuxconfig.org/images/04-set-configure-static-ip-address-ubuntu-18.04-bionic-linux.png

Comment: Thanks @chili555. I was hoping to accomplish this through command line as I've disabled the GUI on the VM that I'm supporting.

Comment: Then netplan is your friend! See the template at `cat /usr/share/doc/netplan/examples/static.yaml`

Comment: Thanks @chili555 one more question -- do you know if there's an easier way to just run a command to keep it permanently? Or will I need to build a script to parse the YAML file and edit it that way?

Comment: I'm not very familiar with such things. Doesn't the VM save a snapshot including any changes you've made?

Comment: Gotcha. It does, but only if you restore to the snapshot. I was looking for something similar to running it quickly via CLI and having it permanently. I'll work on figuring out how to do this through the YAML file. I really appreciate the pointer.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/119249/discussion-between-chili555-and-user3447014).